# HTML-How to automatically generate infinite different modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on creating a Project Manager website using w3school's [To-do-list tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp). I have added a detail button (the `...`) that shows a modal that shows information about the task, and I have to manually create the modal for the tasks.

My question is: Is there any way to generate infinitely different modal for each element on the list.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
// Click on a detail button to show detail of the current list item
var detail = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");
var count = 0; // count number of task (must < then 10)
var maxcount = 10;

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    if (count < maxcount) {
      count = count + 1;
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
  // Create close button for each element
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  // Create detail button for each element
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u2026");
  span.className = "detail";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  // Function of close button
  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      count = count - 1;
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var detail = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");
  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modalclose");
  // Funtion of detail button 

  detail[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event0) {
    if (event0.target == modal[0]) {
      modal[0].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event1) {
    if (event1.target == modal[1]) {
      modal[1].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event2) {
    if (event2.target == modal[2]) {
      modal[2].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event3) {
    if (event3.target == modal[3]) {
      modal[3].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event4) {
    if (event4.target == modal[4]) {
      modal[4].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event5) {
    if (event5.target == modal[5]) {
      modal[5].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event6) {
    if (event6.target == modal[6]) {
      modal[6].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event7) {
    if (event7.target == modal[7]) {
      modal[7].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[8].onclick = function() {
    modal[8].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[8].onclick = function() {
    modal[8].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event8) {
    if (event8.target == modal[8]) {
      modal[8].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  detail[9].onclick = function() {
    modal[9].style.display = "block";
  }
  span[9].onclick = function() {
    modal[9].style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event9) {
    if (event9.target == modal[9]) {
      modal[9].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}


/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Remove margins and padding from the list */

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Style the list items */

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 25%;
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}


/* Darker background-color on hover */

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}


/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}


/* Style the close button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the detail button */

.detail {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 11px 16px;
}

.detail:hover {
  background-color: #005ce6;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #0071C5;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}


/* Clear floats after the header */

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the input */

input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Style the "Add" button */

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The modalClose Button */

.modalclose {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modalclose:hover,
.modalclose:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">
    <p contenteditable="true">Edit task's name</p>
  </h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn"> Add </span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date1:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date2:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date3:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal4" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date4:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal5" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date5:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal6" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date6:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal7" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date7:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal8" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date8:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal9" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date9:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal10" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date10:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommended you to learn OOP, specifically ES6 classes. Implement a modal class, include the event listeners and other methods needed in the class. Then you can create multiple parametrized instances from the class easily, and also remove them from the DOM when the modal will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps -

1. Create a `<div id="dynamicDiv">` in your page where you want to show the modals
2. Using JS manually write the modal descriptions as a string in a variable like `var modalDesc = '... my modal description as html ...'` for each modal
3. Put the string inside the div like - `document.getElementById('dynamicDiv').innerHTML = modalDesc1 + '<br>' + modalDesc2 ...`

**UPDATED**

For multiple cases you may use loops but works only when your modal structures are same but information or the structural values are different.

Else you'll have to declare each modal in different ways

Comment: But then you still have to create many modals manually. Is there any solution for the code to automatically generate the modals using loop or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

1. You should not directly change style with css, if avoidable. Better change the `className` of elements (with `.classList.add`/`.remove`/`.toggle`)
2. Better not use `.onclick` handler, but use
   `.addEventListener('click', /* function reference here */)`
3. You don't need infinitely many click handlers, Just use a click handler on the the document, The click event bubbles up to the document (if not interrupted) and there you can check the `.target` of the event
4. `document.getElementsByClassName` is a *live* `HTMLCollection`. That means, if you dynamically add new elements with that class or remove existing ones, it will be reflected in the items of that HTMLCollection on-the-fly.
5. Since you add `.details` and `.modals` simultaneously, they have the same index in their respective HTMLCollections `details` and `modals`. I therefore check the index of the clicked `.detail` element in the `details` HTMLCollection and then toggle the `className` of the element with the same index in the `modals` collection.
6. Remove all of the static HTML modal except for one, give id of `modal-template`. On click on `Add` button you clone this template (`.cloneNode(true)`), remove id, add class and change count in Due Date, and then append to body

```js
console.clear();
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
// Click on a detail button to show detail of the current list item
var detail = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");
//var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modalclose");
var modalTemplate = document.getElementById('modal-template')

var count = 0; // count number of task (must < then 10)
var maxcount = 10;

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    if (count < maxcount) {
      count = count + 1;
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
  // Create close button for each element
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  // Create detail button for each element
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u2026");
  span.className = "detail";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  // Function of close button
  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      count = count - 1;
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var clone = modalTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  clone.removeAttribute('id')
  clone.classList.add('modal')
  
  clone.querySelector('.due-date-count').insertAdjacentText('beforeBegin', count)
  clone.querySelector('.due-date-count').remove()
  document.body.appendChild(clone, 'beforeEnd')
  

}


function closeModal(modal) {
  modal.classList.remove('visible')
}
function openModal(modal) {
  modal.classList.add('visible')
}
function toggleModal(modal) {
  modal.classList.toggle('visible')
}

// Funtion of detail button 

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('detail')) {
    toggleModal(modal[Array.from(detail).indexOf(e.target)])
  } else if (!e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
    Array.from(modal).forEach(function(modal) {closeModal(modal)})
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains('modalclose')){
    closeModal(e.target.closest('.modal'))
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}


/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Remove margins and padding from the list */

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#modal-template {
  display: none;
}


/* Style the list items */

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 25%;
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}


/* Darker background-color on hover */

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}


/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}


/* Style the close button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the detail button */

.detail {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 11px 16px;
}

.detail:hover {
  background-color: #005ce6;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #0071C5;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}


/* Clear floats after the header */

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the input */

input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Style the "Add" button */

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal.visible {
  display: block;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The modalClose Button */

.modalclose {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modalclose:hover,
.modalclose:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2 style="margin:5px">
    <p contenteditable="true">Edit task's name</p>
  </h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn"> Add </span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-template">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="modalclose">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Due date <span class="due-date-count"></span>:</p>
      <input type="date" name="duedate">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>In charge person WWID:</p>
      <input type="number" name="WWID">
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Comment:</p>
      <input type="text" name="WWID" placeholder="Insert your comment here...">
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that makes the script look clean. But I still have to create modals in the HTML code. Is there any solution for the modal to create for itself ?

Comment: @KThong I addressed this in item 6 on the list (edited)