# How to create an element dynamically in an html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, element, creation

I am learning to create an element dynamically in an html page using javascript. In this code I am trying to create a simple "h6" inside "div-1".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </header>
    <body>
        <button onclick="constructElement()">click</button>
        <div id="div-1"></div>

        <script>
            function constructElement(){
                var elem = document.createElement("h6");
                elem.innerText("Dynamically added text.")
                document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(elem);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two mistakes in your code
the first is that you used wrong "id" name div-1 instead of div1
also, innerText isn't a function

this is the code after the fix :)

```html
<header>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</header>

<body>

  <button onclick="constructElement()">click</button>

  <div id="div-1">

  </div>

  <script>
    function constructElement() {
      var elem = document.createElement("h6");
      elem.innerText = "Dynamically added text."
      document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(elem);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I used the correct id but messed up at the "innerText" part. Thanks for the answer though. I understand my mistake now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</header>

<body>

    <button onclick="constructElement()">click</button>

    <div id="div-1">

    </div>

    <script>

            function constructElement(){
                var elem = document.createElement("h6");
                elem.innerText= "Dynamically added text.";
                document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(elem);
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the text content of a node: node.innerText = text

```
function constructElement(){
    var elem = document.createElement("h6");
    elem.innerText ="Dynamically added text."
    document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is directly not your answer but the algorithm is very similar

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489422/10941112

(For the part of modals please put your own elements)

In case you  need further clarification feel free to ask as this is not your direct answer

Also sorry to say but the question is a duplicate of -
[Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5536596/10941112)